# How to unlatch relay with relay?

Tags: relay, circuit-design, latch

I have problems with unlatching relay with relay..
Schematics below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZLVn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The purpose for this is to light on car sidelights when car is unlocked, when pressing lock button it turn off sidelights. Car gives negative impulse for locking and/or unlocking.

 My problem - When Door unlock impulse is given then 1st relay latch himself on so the lights are on (OK, thats what i need), but when i give lock impulse it do not energies 2nd relay to turn off sidelights.

 What im doing wrong?

Comment: When RLY2 is off, the top of its coil is connected to (-) through its contact. It will never be able to switch on with this configuration.

Comment: Use a dual-coil latching relay. Problem solved without having current go through a coil all the time either. Medium Power: http://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Omron-Electronics/G2RK-1-DC12/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtGt%252bn33CgIP0yQknHWQsg%2fwddFUSOVSf4%3d  Or in case you also want to connect your starter motor to it: http://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-AMP/1-1414939-4/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtGt%252bn33CgIPxSNzm1YXX8ZBkiA0zhTlxI%3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the coil of RLY2 connected to the wrong place. Just rewire it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHM8lA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: After 1st comment i understand that theres no + to the coil, but your answer was real solution. Somehow i missed it when made this..

Answer (score 1):

> What im doing wrong?

You are not interrupting the power feed to RLY1 - once the doors are unlocked RL1 turns on and no matter what the lock contact does RLY1 will stay on.

Try putting the door unlock contact in series with the NC contact of RL2 and rewiring the power feeds. Alternatively look at this stop/start circuit for ideas: -

[image]

The stop circuit contact is the normally closed contact of RLY2